# Modify value in column based on conditions from another columns pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this example df:

```
start_date   end_date id
22-07-2022 28-07-2022  A
22-07-2022 28-07-2022  B
22-07-2022 17-08-2022  A
```

I need to obtain this result:

```
start_date   end_date id
22-07-2022 28-07-2022  A
22-07-2022 28-07-2022  B
29-07-2022 17-08-2022  A
```

To put it in words, I need to copy the earliest end_date + 1 day from one row with the same id into the another row's start_date, so the dates don't overlap. There will always be 2 rows max per id and the start_date will be the same for both of them.

Right now I'm trying to use a for loop adding conditions but I guess there's a more Pythonic way to do this using pandas functions. Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code defines the same data you provide programmatically and does the type of transformation you seek.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

data = {
    "start_date": ["22-07-2022", "22-07-2022", "22-07-2022"],
    "end_date": ["28-07-2022", "28-07-2022", "17-08-2022"],
    "id": ["A", "B", "A"],
}

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(data)
    .assign(start_date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.start_date, format="%d-%m-%Y"))
    .assign(end_date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.end_date, format="%d-%m-%Y"))
    .sort_values("end_date")
)


df["new_start_date"] = (
    df.groupby("id").end_date.shift() + timedelta(days=1)
).combine_first(df.start_date)
```

In the last line, we group by the `id` variable, and shift each sorted `end_date` of each id forward, leaving a `NaN` like in the first row of the group. Then add an extra day to that column to advance the end date to the next day. Finally, we coalesce/`combine_first` the `start_date` with this new columns fill the gaps.

Comment: Thank you. I used your code, but I got the same start_dates from the first df, meaning they are still overlapped.

Comment: Yep you are right. I didn't understand the transformation you had in mind. I think the updated version is what you are after.